# Create Android qcow2 from QEMU

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, emulation, qemu

I was wondering if it was possible to use QEMU to start the emulator created from the Android Virtual Device Manager in Android Studio? I know it can be started from the command line, but I'm trying to understand how it works underneath. I know the AVD creates a qcow2, but it also creates a lot of other .img files that I'm not sure how to combine into a command that can actually start it.

If I can't start it via QEMU, is it possible to create an Android qcow2 emulator image to run for device testing in the same way? I found a similar guide online (https://yzygitzh.github.io/android/2017/11/03/android-x86-qemu.html), but I haven't gotten it to work so far. I also don't know how it would perform in comparison, specifically for app testing. Would anyone have any insight on that?

Similar Research:

- [Android emulator is based on QEMU. Can I use KVM with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598942/android-emulator-is-based-on-qemu-can-i-use-kvm-with-it) (Kind of beats around the question, but doesn't exactly answer it)
- [Mount qcow2 image created by Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039315/mount-qcow2-image-created-by-android-emulator) (Discusses a bit about the Android Device Emulator files)
- [How to show which options are passed to QEMU when launching the android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445464/how-to-show-which-options-are-passed-to-qemu-when-launching-the-android-emulator) (Seems closer to partially answering the question)
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48310014/9 (Shows building the emulator wrapping around QEMU, but not using the emulator without the wrapper)